# Update collection puts unnecessary doc

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

When i update my collection, then in local collection appears doc `{ _id: undefined }`, after reload page this doc disapear. I tried to do both with methods and with client-side operations - results are identical

And wherein an js error:
*Expected to find a document already present for removed*

And if I update the collection again, then js gives another error:
*Duplicate _id 'undefined'*

Here is my code:

```
Template.depForm.events({
  'submit #dep_form': function(event) {
    var action, dep, form;
    event.preventDefault();
    form = event.target;
    dep = $(form).serializeJSON();
    if (dep.status != null) {
      dep.status["new"] = dep.status["new"] ? true : false;
      dep.status.hidden = dep.status.hidden ? true : false;
    }
    action = this.editDep ? 'update' : 'create';
    return DepartmentsCollection["" + action + "Dep"](dep, function(err) {
      var msg;
      if (err) {
        return alertify.error(err.reason);
      } else {
        msg = action.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + action.slice(1);
        alertify.success(i18n("deps.dep" + msg + "Success"));
        return Router.go("deps");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

and collection:

```
depTitleObj = {};

_.each(i18n.getAvailableLanguages(), function(v) {
  return depTitleObj[v] = {
    type: String
  };
});

depTitleSchema = new SimpleSchema(depTitleObj);

depStatusSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  hidden: {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: true
  },
  "new": {
    type: Boolean,
    optional: true
  }
});

depSchema = SimpleSchema.build(SimpleSchema.timestamp, {
  title: {
    type: depTitleSchema
  },
  synonyms: {
    type: String
  },
  use_count: {
    type: Number,
    optional: true,
    min: 0
  },
  main_dep: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  status: {
    type: depStatusSchema,
    optional: true
  }
});

Departments = new Mongo.Collection('departments');

Departments.attachSchema(depSchema);

allow = function(userId) {
  if (!userId) {
    return false;
  }
  return UsersCollection.findOne({
    _id: userId
  }, {
    fields: {
      role: 1
    }
  }).hasAccess('admin');
};


Departments.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return allow(userId);
  },
  update: function(userId, doc) {
    return allow(userId);
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc) {
    return allow(userId);
  }
});

_.extend(Departments, {
  createDep: function(data, cb) {
    return this.insert(data, cb);
  },
  updateDep: function(data, cb) {
    var depId;
    if (!data._id) {
      return cb(new Meteor.Error("dep-notfound", i18n("deps.errorUpdateNoDepID")));
    }
    depId = data._id;
    delete data._id;
    this.update(depId, {
      "$set": data
    }, cb);
    return true;
  }
});

this.DepartmentsCollection = Departments;

})();
```

### Update 1

I used the function of underscore.js *_.omit()* to eliminate the property _id in form object, but it did not help, and then I manually put the object to update, which also did not help. All this suggests the idea that there is a bug in minimongo.

*updateDep* function in *DepartmentsCollection*:

```
updateDep: function(data, cb) {
    var dep, depId;
    if (!data._id) {
      return cb(new Meteor.Error("dep-notfound", i18n("deps.errorUpdateNoDepID")));
    }
    depId = data._id;
    dep = _.omit(data, "_id");
    console.log(__indexOf.call(dep, "_id") >= 0 ? "true" : "false");
    this.update(depId, {
      "$set": {
        synonyms: dep.synonyms
      }
    }, cb);
    return true;
  }
```

and this is object after `form.serializeJSON()`

[image]

Comment: Please share your code. There is not enough here to go on.

Comment: i shared code, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason for such behavior. the fact is that the field main_dep - a reference to the document in the same collection and to display the additional document on the client side, I added this document as the result of the primary sample. when I was just added this main_dep as a property of the main document, the problem disappeared by itself

Answer (score 0):

Where you do `dep = $(form).serializeJSON();` - this is converting the form fields into the object you are inserting into the `DepartmentsCollection` correct? Is there an `_id` field on the form by any chance? Perhaps you have it there to show the `_id` for an existing record. But because you're pushing *all* the form fields into the object if it wasn't originally set on create then it would exist in the object but be undefined. You'd have to do:

```
if ( !this.editDep ) delete dep._id;
```

To avoid trying to set an undefined `_id` when you create a department.

This is a bit speculative because I can't see your form or what fields you have but it makes sense based on the error you're reporting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried to change the code by following your recommendations. The problem still not resolved, please see my question after "Update 1"